# Determining recurrence of running time of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, stl-algorithm

I have a Computer Science assignment to determine recurrence of algorithm given as:

```
public void foobar(int n)
if n < 0
   return
foobar (n/3)
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i = i+1)
    for (int j = n; j >= 1; j = j/2)
        print(i+j)
foobar(2n/3)
for (int i = 1; i >= 5000; i = i+1)
    print(i)
```

I know about basic relation like:

> T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3) + time for other stuff

I am unable to determine the running time of loops at each recursive call . Any help would be much appreciated and would greatly help in my studies, Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure about `if n > 0 return`? and `i >= 5000`?

Comment: ooh sorry n < 0

Comment: no it will not run ... because i = 1 .. so only outer and inner loop below foobar(n/3)

Comment: Your nested loops have the complexity `O(n*log(n))` because `i` iterates through `n` different values, `j` iterates through approximately `log(n)` values and these two loops are independent. Your last loop has `O(1)` complexity.

Comment: ok got it .... thank u so much ...... inner loop was teasing me ....:)

Comment: T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3) + O(n*log(n)) ..... am i right .. ?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: ok man ..... thank u.......